# after updating Xubuntu empty desktop

Tags: xubuntu

Yesterday my wife updated Xubuntu on her laptop.

The login screen is still OK (16.04 LTS, wired connection present).
But after logging in the desktop is empty (nothing more than a purple background).
The mousecursor is visible and right-clicking only gives limited options (new map, new document, open terminal, change desktop order, change background).

Can someone give me a simple (I'm a novice) solution?

grx, Graard